# Функция-конвертер XML->JSON

Tags: xml, delphi, json

Очень нужна функция для конвертирования XML в JSON

Признаюсь честно - писать свою лень, т. к. почти уверен, что таковая есть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите [JSON – SuperObject](http://www.progdigy.com/?page_id=6)

> XML to JSON parser

А также [tiny-json](http://code.google.com/p/tiny-json/)

> ... unit for Delphi, which realizes parsing and generating JSON format ...

Comment: Спасибо!
Использовал SuperObject
То что надо!